# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing When Close WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium

[image]

I have this error when try to close my driver.
I try `driver.Close()`, `driver.Quit()` and always i have this message.
i am using `Visual Studio 2013` and try to install `Visual C++ Redistr` (both x64 and x86) and this still not helped.
This error happening only when i try to close the browser at the end of my surfing.